# Angular 4, One way data binding View to Component

Tags: typescript, angular2-forms

I have a form to get user credentials. Before using those credentials I need to encrypt them, but if I do as it follows, the encrypted values are shown into the form component (because of the 2-way data binding).

I'm new to Angular, and I can't find a way to pass input values to my typescript model. 
Here is the code:

```
<form>
        <div class="input-group">
          <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></i></span>
          <input class="form-control" placeholder="Username" [(ngModel)]="user.username"
                 [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}">
        </div>
        <br>
        <div class="input-group">
          <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-lock"></i></span>
          <input class="form-control" type="password" placeholder="Password" [(ngModel)]="user.password"
                 [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}">
        </div>
        <br>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block" autofocus (click)="login(user)">
          Login
        </button>
</form>
```

And of course the user definition

```
user = {
  username: '',
  password: ''
};
```

How do I avoid the 2 way data binding to the model [()] ? I tried (input) or {{}} but nothig worked.

Thanks to all

Comment: I do not have component interaction, like in the example, father-child component. I have to pass values from the View (html) part of the component to the Logic (ts) of the same component

Comment: I'm sorry by my mistake I palaced wrong link. Here in [Angular Froms documentation](https://angular.io/guide/forms) you have example of one way and two way data binding.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved My problem because  I don't need to encrypt them anymore